# HTML mirroring, linking

Tags: html, apache

I have two servers with apache httpd on it.
One of them is accessible from anywhere, but the other is restricted at specific internet provider. Is there a way to make a link or a mirror for the second server?

My idea is to show the websites from the second server using the first server. So the user accesses the first server, the first server sends the request to the second and displays the response to the user.

How can this be done?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `mod_rewrite` for this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/proxy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your wanting is called a proxy. With apache you can do this with ProxyPass or ProxyPassReverse, depending on the desired effect. This is provided by [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). You could also set up a lighter weight server with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule), or other similar type servers.

From apaches ex. If you had secondserver.com then you can use

```
ProxyPass / http://firstserver.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it.

Comment: Didn't succeed with this until now, but as I see this is the right answer. I just needed the name of the methodology. Thank you!